# string.Compare(String, Int32, String, Int32, Int32) is not compared correctly for Thai Culture in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#

In the code snippet below. In the case of Thai Culture, the result should be `-1`, but it is `0`.

Is anyone aware of the reason for this?

```
public void CountryCulture()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH");
    string value1 = "#,##0.00";
    string value2 = ";";
    int result = string.Compare(value1, 0, value2, 0, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: `string.Compare(value1, 0, value2, 0, 1, true, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("th-TH"))` gives `-1`

Comment: What is the purpose of the indices and lengths? Why not just write the example as `string.Compare("#", ";", false, new CultureInfo("th-TH"))`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- As [spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender) pointed out [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058659/string-comparestring-int32-string-int32-int32-is-not-compared-correctly-fo#comment127323288_72058659), the expected result of the comparison should be `-1`. not `1`.
- Assuming you've added the line changing the current culture for reproducibility reasons, your code can be condensed to:

  ```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH");
  var result = string.Compare("#", ";");
  Console.WriteLine(result); // Writes 0 on .NET 5; writes -1 on .NET Framework
  ```
- The exact value is irrelevant - only its [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics)); the [documentation for the `String.Compare` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare) says:

  > All overloads of the `Compare` method return a 32-bit signed integer indicating the lexical relationship between the two comparands.
  >
  > | Value | Condition |
  > | --- | --- |
  > | Less than zero | The first substring precedes the second substring in the sort order. |
  > | Zero | The substrings occur in the same position in the sort order, or length is zero. |
  > | Greater than zero | The first substring follows the second substring in the sort order. |

---

If you want an expected (i.e. negative) value, there are a few options available:

1. Use an overload which takes a `StringComparison`, e.g. [`Compare(String, String, StringComparison)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-6.0#system-string-compare(system-string-system-string-system-stringcomparison)):

   ```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH");
   var result = string.Compare("#", ";", StringComparison.Ordinal);
   Console.WriteLine(result); // Writes "-24" on .NET 5 and .NET Framework
   ```
2. Use a member of the `String.CompareOrdinal` overload group, e.g. [`CompareOrdinal(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareordinal?view=net-6.0#system-string-compareordinal(system-string-system-string)):

   ```
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH");
   var result = string.CompareOrdinal("#", ";");
   Console.WriteLine(result); // Writes "-24" on .NET 5 and .NET Framework
   ```

---

As for your question

> Is anyone aware of the reason for this?

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) effectively provided it in his link to [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058659/string-comparestring-int32-string-int32-int32-is-not-compared-correctly-fo#comment127324308_72058659).

Quoting a relevant part of the document (emphasis mine):

> Prior to .NET 5, the .NET globalization APIs used different underlying libraries on different platforms. On Unix, the APIs used [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](http://site.icu-project.org/home), and on Windows, they used [National Language Support (NLS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/national-language-support). This resulted in some behavioral differences in a handful of globalization APIs when running applications on different platforms. Behavior differences were evident in these areas:
>
> - Cultures and culture data
> - String casing
> - **String sorting and searching**
> - Sort keys
> - String normalization
> - Internationalized Domain Names (IDN) support
> - Time zone display name on Linux
>
> Starting with .NET 5, developers have more control over which underlying library is used, enabling applications to avoid differences across platforms.
>
> ...
>
> If you upgrade your app to target .NET 5, you might see changes in your app even if you don't realize you're using globalization facilities.